# Bootstrap карусель-слайдер не работает

Tags: bootstrap

```
<div class="carousel slide" id="mySlider">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="active" data-target="#mySlider" data-slide-to="0"></li>
        <li data-target="#mySlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <img src="img/bg.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Header</h4>
                <p>Description Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="img/bg1.jpg" />
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Header</h4>
                <p>Description Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" data-slide="prev" href="#mySlider">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" data-slide="next" href="#mySlider">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Почему не работает слайд??? Я пересмотрел 3 видеоурока, все вроде правильно, но не работает слайд, ни при нажатии на индикаторы внизу, ни при нажатии на стрелки nrxt/previous.

В чем проблема?

Comment: Что в консоли?

Comment: Как проверить? Я с консолью никогда не работал, если честно. Но при запуске там пусто(>)

Comment: В гуглохроме: открыть страницу, нажать f12, вкладка Console. Если там ошибок нет, то показать js код вызова слайдера, а лучше ссылку на сайт.

Comment: @Лисёнок, не вводите человека в заблуждение. Во-первых, по F12 увеличивается громкость, а консоль открывается по Cmd+Option+J, во-вторых, этот слайдер не нуждается в js-коде вызова, в третьих, предъявленный код абсолютно рабочий, что можно видеть на http://jsfiddle.net/7MyJ6/1/ , а значит, проблема, если она вообще есть, совсем не здесь.

Comment: а js кода ведь нет. Там я bootstrap.css прикрепил и работаю с ним

Comment: вот. Это и есть ошибка. bootstrap.js тоже надо подключить.

Comment: я впервые с bootstrap начинаю работать. Этого не знал. Сейчас, попробую. @Елена Левина

ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО! Сработало!

Comment: предположение подтвердилось. У вас действительно не подключен bootstrap.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот ваш код: http://jsfiddle.net/7MyJ6/ Изменены только адреса картинок, просто чтобы было.

В чём проблема?

А вот он изменён ровно на один css-класс, чтобы кадры менялись с анимацией: http://jsfiddle.net/7MyJ6/1/

Update: и да, у вас не подключен bootstrap.js, Закономерно не работает. Подключите, и всё будет хорошо. Сам код корректный.

Comment: а класс slide и у меня есть. Смотрите в код мой выложенный тут. Но все же не работает

Comment: @uzumaxy, никакой магии. У меня нормально подключается bootstrap с bootstrapcdn

Comment: И о5 магия, Я удалил коммент, как только написал, а Вы его прочитали...

Comment: @navi1893, это сейчас он есть. В моём первом примере код просто скопирован из вашего оригинального вопроса: http://hashcode.ru/revisions/287382/ , под номером 1. Единственное изменение - картинки существующие добавлены. А во втором - да, добавлен класс slide, но единственное, на что он влияет, это то, на что он и должен влиять: анимация сдвигом. Всё же покажите неработающий вариант. Проблема явно не в этой части кода.

Comment: @uzumaxy, и опять никакой магии :) Я прочитала коммент на почте, и прямо с почты иду по ссылке отвечать. Вижу уже после ответа, что коммента, на который отвечаю, нет - думаю, глюк сервиса. Или магия ;) Ан нет, и это рационально объясняется :)

Comment: @Елена Левина это весь код, то что последний раз я выложил/исправил. Другого кода нет. Подключил bootstrap и написал это все. Внизу появились индикаторы, стрелки по бокам, но они не рабочие. Нажимаю и на индикаторы, и на стрелки, но не работают

Comment: понятно, что ничего не понятно. Ошибка всё равно не в этой части. Если есть возможность, давайте ссылку на страницу. Либо постарайтесь её воспроизвести на jsfiddle.

Answer (score -1):

Добавить `data-ride="carousel"` в `<div id="myCarousel">`.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?